# Matlab/Excel/R: Transforming an unbalanced dataset depending on value of column

Tags: r, excel, matlab

I have a an unbalanced dataset with intraday data and would like to columnwise split it into a matrix depending on the day the given observation is from.

Short example follows. A matrix A:

```
A = [1 5; 1 5; 1 6; 2 4; 2 2; 3 8; 3 4];
```

where the first column is the day indicator and the second an observed value, should be transformed into a matrix B:

```
B = [5 4 8; 5 2 4; 6 nan nan];
```

I don't care if it's solved in Matlab, R or excel, it's a one time thing for me.

Thanks,
J.

Comment: We are not mechanical turks that would do your work for you.

Comment: In `R` one way would be: `A <- matrix(c(1,5,1,5, 1,6,2,4, 2,2, 3,8,3,4),ncol=2, byrow=TRUE); lst <- split(A[,2], A[,1]);  do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_along(lst[[1]]), function(i) sapply(lst,`[`, i)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in Matlab:

```
A = [1 5; 1 5; 1 6; 2 4; 2 2; 3 8; 3 4];

nMaxDays = max(A(:, 1));
nMaxSamples = max(accumarray(A(:, 1), 1));

mnSamplesMatrix = nan(nMaxSamples, nMaxDays);

for (nDay = unique(A(:, 1))')
   vnThisDay = A(A(:, 1) == nDay, 2);
   mnSamplesMatrix(1:numel(vnThisDay), nDay) = vnThisDay;
end
```